# Count the number of scales

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursive-query

I have the following table:

**History of routes**

```
+----+-----------------+-----------------+---------------+-----------------+--------------+
| id |departure        | arrival         |terminal_ori_id| terminal_dest_id|next_route_id |
+----+-----------------+-----------------+---------------+-----------------+--------------+
| 8  |2020-05-01 12:00 |2020-05-01 17:00 |5              | 1               |  [null]      |       
| 9  |2020-05-01 08:00 |2020-05-01 10:00 |4              | 5               |  8           |            
| 10 |2020-05-01 03:00 |2020-05-01 07:00 |3              | 4               |  9           |            
+----+---------------------+-----------------+---------------+-----------------+--------------+
```

I want to print the departure and arrival time in a certain format, the name of the terminals and the number of scales the flight has. For example, flight #10 has scale to flight #9 and flight #9 has scale to flight #8. So flight #10 has 2 scales and flight #9 has 1 scale. Is there a way to do that?

Here's what I have of the query:

```
SELECT h.id,
       to_char(h.departure, 'Mon DD YYYY HH:12:MI AM') departure, 
       to_char(h.arrival, 'Mon DD YYYY HH:12:MI AM') arrival, 
       t.name as terminal_origin,
       td.name as terminal_destiny,
FROM history_of_routes h
JOIN terminals t ON t.id = h.terminal_ori_id
JOIN terminals td ON td.id = h.terminal_dest_id;
```

I'm just missing the scales part, I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Didn't know that's called "scale".

Comment: i translated real quick from spanish, idk what's the correct word tbh

Comment: Hops? Connection flights? Not sure myself ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [recursive CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) would do the job:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   SELECT id, 0 AS scale, next_route_id
   FROM   history_of_routes h

   UNION ALL
   SELECT c.id, c.scale + 1, h.next_route_id
   FROM   cte c
   JOIN   history_of_routes h ON h.id = c.next_route_id
   WHERE  c.next_route_id IS NOT NULL  -- end of path
)
SELECT id, scale
FROM   cte
WHERE  next_route_id IS NULL;
```

Result:

```
root_id | scale
------: | ----:
      8 |     0
      9 |     1
     10 |     2
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1046a3fd4438f3f0c1cec8815af17212)*

Assuming that `next_route_id IS NULL` terminates each flight path.
Integrated:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   SELECT id, 0 AS scale, next_route_id
   FROM   history_of_routes h

   UNION ALL
   SELECT c.id, c.scale + 1, h.next_route_id
   FROM   cte c
   JOIN   history_of_routes h ON h.id = c.next_route_id
   WHERE  c.next_route_id IS NOT NULL  -- end of path
)
SELECT c.id
     , c.scale
     , to_char(h.departure, 'Mon DD YYYY HH:12:MI AM') AS departure
     , to_char(h.arrival  , 'Mon DD YYYY HH:12:MI AM') AS arrival
     , o.name AS terminal_origin
     , d.name AS terminal_destiny
FROM   cte c
JOIN   history_of_routes h USING (id)
JOIN   terminals o ON o.id = h.terminal_ori_id
JOIN   terminals d ON d.id = h.terminal_dest_id
WHERE  c.next_route_id IS NULL;
```